# JSON.stringify() or default url encoding for data posted via ajax?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-web-api

What is the difference or advantage of posting a complex object using `JSON.stringify()` over simply allowing the default url encoding of the data, when using the `jQuery.ajax` functions?
The MVC WebApi I am posting to is able to correctly route and parse both requests, so there is no '*explicit*' need to send JSON to the server.
Additionally, because CORS is enabled on the server, posting json emits a preflight OPTIONS request (I understand why...that is not my question), whereas using the default encoding does not, thus saving one network call which would '*seem*' to be advantageous from a performance standpoint.

Both of these ajax calls work. I've tested with an object that also contains an embedded sub-object and an embedded array:

```
var item = {
    Name: "Joe", 
    Team: "Yankees", 
    Vitals: { Age: 21, Height: "6'0" }, 
    Positions: ["1st", "Right", "DH"]};

// using default url-encoding
$.post(apiUri, item)
.done(function () {alert("Done");})
.fail(function () {alert("Fail");});

// posting a json string
$.ajax({
    url: apiUri,
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(item),
    type: "POST"
})
.done(function () {alert("Done");})
.fail(function () {alert("Fail");});
```

However, many ajax to web-api examples seem to favor posting data as a json string.

Guidelines or advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference or advantage of posting JSON using JSON.stringify() over the default url encoding of the data using the jQuery.ajax functions?

This is really not quite comparable as you're missing the content type.  In other words Posting JSON as x-www-form-urlencoded simply doesn't work.  So I'll adjust your question to be more specific:

> What is the difference or advantage of posting JSON using JSON.stringify() with the content type set to `application/json` over the default url encoding (`x-www-form-urlencoded`/Querystring) of the data using the jQuery.ajax functions?

In my opinion (but still factual), the biggest and most beneficial advantage is that when you use JSON instead of a Form Querystring, the amount of work required to correctly bind the values to a class using the default model binder is minimal.  Assuming the web-api uses the same model binder as MVC (I'm pretty sure it does) bind form values can be [quite tedious and difficult to debug](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/).  This tends not to be the case when posting simple name value pairs.

Comment: Yes, that was incorrect wording on my part, and I just corrected it. I just want to post non-primitive data. I should not have said 'post JSON'. However, the rest of your answer is the kind of explanation I am looking for.